# Scrollbar not scrolling completely down the page on mobile device

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

Just to get straight to the problem: I am developing a sidebarmenu on HTML and CSS. Everything works fine on Computer devices but when it comes to mobile devices the page doesn't scroll till the end of the page. I don't know where the issue is but I am gonna provide the code that I wrote so somebody can probably help me to solve this issue.

HTML Part

```
<div class="sidemenu">
    <div class="topmenu">
        /* The rest of the code
    </div>
    <div class="menucontent">
        /* The rest of the code
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Part

```
.sidemenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
.topmenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 84px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.menucontent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: calc(100% - 84px);
    max-height: calc(100% - 84px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I just replaced height: 100vh from sidebar to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix. You have set `position: fixed` on **side menu**. Delete that and it scrolls normally